# Adobe Air Browser

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, browser, air, adobe

Im trying to implement a mini browser in adobe air.  The browser should work in the same ways as a mobile phone browser, i.e.  fit the width of the website to a certain width(specified within the html component) and leave the height to be scrollable.

I have managed to do a mini browser by using the scaleX,scaleY properties of the mx:HTML component however these make the websites look unreadable.

I have also tried setting the css3 zoom property, and that works fine, but it only zooms out certain elements, therefore messing up the site layout.

My question is:  Is there a way to make a mini web browser which shows the full content of the website?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Air browser cannot be scaled without have an horrible look (no anti-aliasing).

Answer (score 0):

A few years later but here is what I ended up doing:

The requirement was to show the full website that person B was looking at so that person A could guide them through the site.  Due to all the limitations of the Adobe AIR Browser we ended up using IECapt (http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) within an external process to capture the screenshot and send it back to AIR.

This is all well and good, but IECapt is quite out of date as well so recently we have started to look at the using Chromium (http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/) as an ANE within our application and with that we can alter the zoom and dimensions of the page while still being able to keep it up-to-date.